# Cancelling an NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Is there a method provided in the native SDK to cancel the URL request made? 
I know this method:

```
[connection cancel]
```

But I am wondering if we can cancel a request. I only want to use the native SDK and I am not allowed to use the third party libraries. 
Also is there a way to track the progress of the download with the native library?

Comment: For the second part, check [NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate_Protocol/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate.html)

Comment: @ ACB Thanks. This definitely helps and answers my second part.

Comment: For the first part what is the issue with `[connection cancel]`?

Comment: The connection will terminate. I want to know if there is a method for cancelling a request.

Comment: That is the way to cancel a request. By calling cancel on its url connection. A request is only fired after you have initialized with an NSURLConnection as `theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`. So you have to cancel the connection. Not the request.

Comment: Thanks ACB. This answers my first part too!

Comment: @ACB I do not want to start a new thread on this topic, but is there a way to retry the connection if it times out?

Comment: You have to manually do that. Once it times out, it will call the error delegate. There you can try to do this. It will call the `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method and then you need to create a new URL connection. Check this link for more details. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:

Comment: Do what? Is the comment complete?

Comment: Check my comment again. I have added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you need to call cancel on the NSURLConnection as `[connection cancel]`.

As per [NSURLRequest documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequest):

> NSURLRequest encapsulates two basic data elements of a load request:
>   the URL to load, and the policy to use when consulting the URL content
>   cache made available by the implementation.

And as per [NSURLConnection documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> An NSURLConnection object provides support to perform the loading of a
>   URL request. The interface for NSURLConnection is sparse, providing
>   only the controls to start and cancel asynchronous loads of a URL
>   request.

So you are canceling a URL connection and not a URL request.

For the second part, check the [NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate_Protocol/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate/NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate.html). It has the following delegate methods for this purpose.

```
– connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:
– connectionDidResumeDownloading:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:
– connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:
```